# Where can I get the source code of string.h; not function prototypes, but implementation of functions

Tags: c

[String.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/string.h.html)

I found this while searching about `string.h`. Where can I find the source code of functions defined in `string.h`?

i.e [say] source code of

```
void    *memcpy(void *, const void *, size_t);
```

Also I want to ask how to make your functions as an interface with its implmentation hidden from developer as `string.h` functions has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's memmove](https://code.ohloh.net/search?s=memmove.c) from Ohloh's code search.

Answer (score -1):

Put your function declarations in a .h file and your implementation in a .c file. Compile the .c file into a .o file (.obj on Windows) and link it together with your code.

For the implementation of string.h functions, get the GNU libc source.

Comment: Thanks.
Why do we use _PROTOTYPE e.g.
_PROTOTYPE( void *memset, (void *_s, int _c, size_t _n)  
I saw it in MINIX3 source code
http://www.minix3.org/doc/AppendixB.html